# Declare an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct, declare

I am trying to create an array of structures but it appears this bug:

"Error, array type as  incomplete element type"

```
typedef struct {
char data[MAX_WORD_SIZE];     
int total_count;       
Occurrence_t reference[MAX_FILES];    
int nfiles;         
} Word_t;

struct Word_t array[a];
```

Comment: Did you mean `Word_t array[a];` (without the `struct`)?

Comment: I propose to remove `typedef` from "Beginner's C". If grown up they will drop it anyway. :-)

Comment: @alk - Careful, such rhetoric can start a flame war (from experience, since I share your view :) )

Comment: I am in my first year in college. I just learned to do it with typedef, don't really know another way. But thanks for your help, I just had to remove "struct". Thank you

Comment: Just do it straight forward: Type definition: `struct Word  {...};` Variable definition: 

`struct Word words[42];`

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

Either change you struct definition

```
struct Word_t {
char data[MAX_WORD_SIZE];     
int total_count;       
Occurrence_t reference[MAX_FILES];    
int nfiles;         
};
```

Or (and not both), the array declaration:

```
Word_t array[a];
```

---

What you did is define an un-named structure, to which you gave an alternative name with a typedef. There is no `struct Word_t`, only a `Word_t` type defined.

The tag namespace (where the names that you use after `struct`/`union`/`enum` reside) is separate from the global namespace (where file scope `typedef`ed names reside).

Many programmers feel that lugging around a `struct tag` type name is cumbersome, and you should always do a typedef for the struct name. [Others](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html) feel this is an abuse of typedef-ing, and that the keyword conveys a lot of meaning; to them the typedef is syntactic sugar without any real abstraction.

Whichever way you choose to write you code, stick to it, and don't confuse the two namespaces.

Comment: Rookie mistake. Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

You are using typedef in the first place hence you are not supposed to write the struct anymore . look here

```
typedef struct {
    char data[MAX_WORD_SIZE];     
    int total_count;       
    Occurrence_t reference[MAX_FILES];     
    int nfiles;         
} Word_t;
Word_t array[a];
```

It will work