# How to initialize arrays inside a structure

Tags: c, avr

I am trying to initialize this Kind of structure but it just won't work. Any ideas what the problem is over here?

```
    #include <stdint.h>
    #define txBufLen 3

    struct {
        uint8_t Buf[txBufLen];
        uint16_t out;
        uint16_t len;
    }txBuf;


struct txBuf a = {{1, 2, 3}, 5, 3 };
```

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? If there's an error message, it's a good idea to include it in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by it won't work? Do you get an error? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: Answer is here. Though not an exact dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831826/declare-an-array-of-structures/43831845#43831845

Comment: You've declared a variable of an unnamed `struct` and afterwards using it as a type. That's a no-no. So what is `foo`?

Comment: place `txBuf` just after `struct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct {
    uint8_t Buf[txBufLen];
    uint16_t out;
    uint16_t len;
}txBuf;
```

This defined an untagged struct type, and immediately created a global variable of that type.

You need to change the definition to this:

```
struct txBuf {
    uint8_t Buf[txBufLen];
    uint16_t out;
    uint16_t len;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives compilation error -

```
struct {
    uint8_t Buf[txBufLen];
    uint16_t out;
    uint16_t len;
}txBuf;
```

The above declares a variable `txBuf`.
Change above to -

```
struct txBuf {
    uint8_t Buf[txBufLen];
    uint16_t out;
    uint16_t len;
};
```